# Doing graphics and drawings in a C++ Win32 client/frame area

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, win32gui

How does one write code to make drawings in the Windows main client area of a Win32 C++ app?
I found an example online that uses the "eclipse" API but when I put it in my program, the IDE complained so it would not compile.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean basic drawing (primitives, rendering bitmaps, stuff like that), then GDI and GDI+ are most likely what you want. I haven't used GDI+ much, but [theForger's Win32 API tutorial](http://winprog.org/tutorial/) will show you how to work with bitmaps. Drawing primitives is more GDI+ territory, and I can really only refer you to [the MSDN GDI+ documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f4d4txw) for details of those functions.

If you're looking for game-type graphics, on the other hand, then you might need to research DirectX or OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

By using [GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions in the WM_PAINT handler of the form.

[Here](http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson12.htm) is a site with some examples.